# Using threejs to control a blender object - voice wave animation

Tags: audio, three.js, blender

[image]

I am exploring voice controlled applications and I am wondering if its possible to control a blender model with real-time voice data.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/Audio
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/audio/AudioListener

three.js to control object with actual sound

```
// create an AudioListener and add it to the camera
const listener = new THREE.AudioListener();
camera.add( listener );

// create a global audio source
const sound = new THREE.Audio( listener );

// load a sound and set it as the Audio object's buffer
const audioLoader = new THREE.AudioLoader();
audioLoader.load( 'sounds/ambient.ogg', function( buffer ) {
    sound.setBuffer( buffer );
    sound.setLoop(true);
    sound.setVolume(0.5);
    sound.play();
});
```

https://codepen.io/jhancock532/post/three-js-music-visualiser-tutorial